# Prove that $\int_Xf^p d\mu=\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{0}^{t}p \alpha^{p-1}\lambda_f(\alpha)d\alpha$ where $\lambda_f(\alpha)=\mu({x:f(x) > \alpha})$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ be  measure space and let $f:X \to [0, \infty]$ be measurable. Let $\lambda_f(\alpha)=\mu({x:f(x) > \alpha})$. I want to prove that if $p \geq 1$, $\int_Xf^pd\mu < \infty$, then

$$\int_Xf^p d\mu=\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{0}^{t}p \alpha^{p-1}\lambda_f(\alpha)d\alpha$$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic application of Fubini.

\begin{align}
\int_0^t p \alpha^{p-1} \lambda_f(\alpha)\textrm{d}\alpha &=\int_0^t \int_X p\alpha^{p-1} 1_{\{f>\alpha\}}(x) \textrm{d}\mu(x)\textrm{d}\alpha\\
&=\int_X \int_0^t p\alpha^{p-1} 1_{\{f>\alpha\}}(x)\textrm{d}\alpha\textrm{d}\mu(x) \\
&=\int_X \int_0^{\min \{t,f(x)\}} p\alpha^{p-1} \textrm{d}\alpha\textrm{d}\mu(X)\\
&= \int_X \min\{t,f(x)\}^p\textrm{d}\mu (X)
\end{align}

The desired follows by taking $t\to \infty$ and applying the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: I think it is known as the „layer cake representation“

Comment: That's possible.

Comment: It seems I was right: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation

Comment: Here is a post about the [cake layer integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998633/how-is-fubinis-theorem-used-in-the-following-proof). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828030/an-application-of-fubinis-theorem-and-cake-layer-integration) is yet an other, not yet answered, posting.